# How to align two tf.RandomShuffleQueue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used two `FIFOQueue` to read data (input file and label file), and it works fine. But when use `RandomShuffleQueue`, it seems the input file and label file can't be aligned.

This is a simple example:

Using `FIFOQueue`, everything is OK

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes="int32", shapes=[()])
label_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes ="int32", shapes=[()])

input_op = input_queue.enqueue_many((range(5),))
label_op = label_queue.enqueue_many((range(5),))

input_res = input_queue.dequeue_many(10)
label_res = label_queue.dequeue_many(10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #filled the queue
    for _ in range(10):
        sess.run([input_op,label_op])
    print sess.run([input_res,label_res])
```

The order in input and label data are matching.

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32), 
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)]
```

But for `RandomShuffleQueue`

```
input_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=2, 
                                    dtypes="int32", shapes=[()])
label_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=2, 
                                    dtypes ="int32", shapes=[()])
```

Order changes as below:

```
[array([1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0], dtype=int32), 
 array([3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 3], dtype=int32)]
```

You can see, it's not aligned.
How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `single Queue` to read both inputs and labels together than managing two separate Queues as done below:

```
input_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=2, 
                                dtypes=[tf.int32, tf.int32], shapes=[[],[]])
data = tf.range(5)
label = tf.range(5)
enqueue_op = input_queue.enqueue_many([data, label])
dequeue = input_queue.dequeue_many(10)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   #filled the queue
   for _ in range(10):
      sess.run(enqueue_op)
   print (sess.run(dequeue))
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3], dtype=int32), 
array([1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: your suggestion is very helpful to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I find a useful option in the API that is `seed`

```
input_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=2, 
                                    dtypes="int32", shapes=[()], seed=1234)
label_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=2, 
                                    dtypes="int32", shapes=[()], seed=1234)
```

> [array([4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3], dtype=int32), 
>     array([4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3], dtype=int32)]